# How to resolve spawning two monsters on one tile in Castle Ravenloft

Tags: castle-ravenloft, dnd-adventure-system

Castle Ravenloft is a new game, but already it's struck a chord with me.  I enjoy playing it.

One problem with it being a new game is that the rules and errata haven't quite been fleshed out .

What happens when you spawn two monsters on one tile?

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

On each tile, there is a skull pile on the floor.  When the first monster is placed on the tile, it is placed on the skull tile.

Each subsequent monster placed on that tile is placed as close to the skull pile as possible, so any square adjacent to it.

I believe this is stated in the rulebook, but I don't have it in fromt of me, so I will add the page number later.

**Second:**

I'm not sure that there is a huge need for house rules.  I think that the rules are succinct and well written.  I think that it can be easy to put too much thought into this game, and if you let go of the need to make it "D&D", you will find that the rules work quite nicely without customization *'needed'*.

I really enjoy this game and take it out whenever I can.

Answer (score 2):

From page 11 of the [*Castle Ravenloft*™](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Castle_Ravenloft_RuleBook.pdf) game's rulebook, and again in [*Wrath of Ashardalon*™'s](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Wrath_Ashardalon_RuleBook.pdf) one (which is the second title that uses the *D&D® Adventure System*):

> ✦ If the tactic requires the Monster to move to a new tile, place the Monster on the new tile’s bone pile if that square is empty. Whenever possible, Monsters move from tile to 
>   tile by following the bone pile. **If the bone pile square is occupied, place the Monster anywhere on the tile.**

*Emphasis mine.*

In *Wrath of Ashardalon*™, scorches performs the same function of piles of bones in *Castle Ravenloft*™. (I wonder if they're going to use spider swarms or webs to mark special squares on the upcoming *Legend of Drizzt*™).